# File can't be deleted after it was opened by Itext PdfReader

Tags: java, itext

The following test code fails when f.delete() is called. Any idea why `PdfReader#close()` does not work properly? I need partial reading. I'm using Itext library version 5.5.13 with openjdk 11 on a windows 10 machine.

```java
    @Test
    public void test() throws IOException {
        File f = new File("d:\\EmptyPdf.pdf");
        try {
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(f.getAbsolutePath(), null, true);
            pdfReader.close();
        } finally {
            Assert.assertTrue(f.delete());
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Hi, There is no error message. f.delete() returns false and the file was not deleted.

Comment: @Abra - That won't help.  `pdfReader `won't be set to anything if `new PdfReader` throws, which I assume is what you're thinking.  I don't see any way for `pdfReader` to be set to a value and yet `pdfReader.close()` not be called.

Comment: Try to use the `Files.delete(path)` method instead. This one throws exception with message if can not delete a file. It will give you a clue what is going wrong.

Comment: Hi, It says that the process can not access the file because it's used by an other process. The file is only used by the PdfReader... by the way when i use a different consturctor e.g. the one with the inputstream or a byte[] than the file can be deleted. (but then it's not partial loaded.)

Answer (score -1):

Do not use path, but InputStream

```
    try(InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f)) {
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(is);
        pdfReader.close();
    }
```